# В чем отличие между .NET Core SDK и .NET Core Runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, runtime

В чем отличие между .NET Core SDK и .NET Core Runtime и что нужно ставить разработчику и пользователю моей программы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **SDK** (Software Developer Kit) - для разработки ПО и т.д.
- **Runtime** - для запуска ПО.

Пользователю вашей программы нужно ставить `Runtime` (как не странно).

Comment: Вообще по идеи, да, но я решил проверить прав ли я в Гугле, но ответа не нашел. А нужно ли мне ставить Runtime? (я разработчик)

Comment: @Editaw5, https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7235 .Если ты установишь SDK то получишь сразу и Runtime